# VLC 3.0.0 not saving any recorded file

Tags: vlc-media-player, recording

While playing a mp4 file, I press Record button on VLC 3.0.0 and it turns blue. When after a while a press it again it turns no more blue.
But even if I set the folder of recorded files I don't find any recorded file anywhere in my pc!
When using previous VLC versions I can easily record any mp4 file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
It was the Windows Defender's "Controlled Folder Access" feature preventing VLC from saving any new file any where!